# "80040154 Class not registered" with Word interop from C#

Tags: c#, office-interop

```
try
{
    if (lblCVName.Text != "")
    {
        object fileName = Convert.ToString(Server.MapPath("~/UploadResume")) + "\\" + lblCVName.Text;
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(Convert.ToString(fileName));
        ext = ext.ToLower();
        if (ext == ".doc" || ext == ".docx" || ext == ".rtf")
        {
            object readOnly = true;
            object isVisible = true;
            object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            Document doc = app.Documents.Open(ref fileName,
                                        ref missing, ref readOnly,
                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref isVisible,
                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            doc.Activate();
            doc.FreezeLayout();
            doc.WebPagePreview();
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Clear();
            string filePath = Convert.ToString(fileName);
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.WriteFile(filePath);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception exx)
{
    Common.SendErrorReportToAdmin(exx.ToString(), "ucViewProfile.ascx"); Response.RedirectToRoute("Error", false);
}
```

I am using xml conversion on server using this link http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17985#additional-information

but I get an error:

> "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))."

Comment: is Microsoft word installed on the machine? which version of it and which references of it did you add to the project?

Comment: Have you deployed the office dll to server?

Comment: And is it the right version of word - you need the same as your interop version or newer. (Standard warning applies: Microsoft [don't recommend using office interop in a server environment](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757) - you ought to be using something else.)

Comment: I am not using dll on server i am using xml according to this link http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17985#additional-information

Comment: OK, but why are you instantiating a `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application` then? And I'd guess that SDK won't work with doc or rtf, just docx.

Comment: Thanks Davide Piras , Rup for your quick Response i have got solution from this link http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2008/01/11/Preview-Word-files-%28docx%29-in-HTML-using-ASPNET-OpenXML-and-LINQ-to-XML.aspx